# Date selection query is not working as expected in Cassandra

Tags: groovy, cassandra

I have a domain class and below is the declaration:

```
class Emp{

static mapWith = "cassandra"
String name
Date doj
}

data:
id                 name              doj
1                  X                 01-01-2010
2                  Y                 01-20-2012
```

Cassandra query:

```
  select * from emp_schema.emp where doj='01-01-2010';
```

Error:
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unable to coerce '01-01-2010' to a formatted date (long)"

Comment: could you please share the definition of the table that you are trying to query?

Answer (score 2):

the format to query dates in cassandra is [`yyyy-mm-dd`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html)

Comment: I am using Cassandra 2.2.3 so in the database table structure for doj field is timestamp.I want to save only date but not time.What are the options to save only date instead of modifying cqlshrc file?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from emp_schema.emp where doj='01-01-2010';
```

Carlos is correct in that Cassandra requires dates to be formatted like `yyy-mm-dd`.

***But this query will only work if `doj` is your partition key.***  If your PRIMARY KEY is not setup to indicate `doj` as the partition key, your query is not possible.

I would specifically design your table to suit your query. This definition partitions on `doj` and clusters on `id` for uniqueness, as multiple emp[loyee]s can probably have the same `doj`:

```
create table emp_by_doj (
    doj date,
    id int,
    name text,
    primary key (doj,id));
```

Then you can query by a specific date, and have multiple rows returned for it:

```
> SELECT * FROM emp_by_doj WHERE doj='2017-06-01';

 doj        | id   | name
------------+------+-------
 2017-06-01 | 7721 | Sarah
 2017-06-01 | 8122 |   Sam

(2 rows)
```